# Prolog: Wrong Evaluation?

Tags: prolog

```
friend(a,b).
friend(b,c).
friend(b,d).
friend(b,e).

realFriends(X,Y) :- friend(X,Y);friend(Y,X).
friendOfFriend(X,Y) :- realFriends(X,Z), realFriends(Z,Y).
```

When I query `friendOfFriend(a,X).` I get:

```
X = c ;
X = d ;
X = e ;
X = a ;
false.
```

But why its outputting `X = a` ? `friendOfFriend(a,a).` should be false.

Comment: The program you wrote is not the program you are running. Because `a` does not appear in the `friend/2` relation.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer You are right, I forgot to add a line. Now you should be able to reproduce.

Comment: Is that what you are aiming at: `friendOfFriend(X,Y) :- realFriends(X,Z), realFriends(Z,Y), X\=Y.` ?

Comment: Figure out what the semicolon means. It doesn't mean what you think it does.

Comment: @TA_intern: why do you think that the use of the semicolon is the problem here? Look at tonik's explanations in the comments below.

Comment: @tiffi yes, you are most likely correct. whenever I see a semicolon like this I get very suspicious, which is why I didn't look more closely before commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `friendOfFriend(a,a).` should be false

(or rather, "not true").

It should, but evidently is not. This is due to the fact that `friendOfFriend(a,a)` can arise by going through one link of the relation `realFriends/2`, and back:

```
friendOfFriend(a,a) :- realFriends(a,Z), realFriends(Z,a).
```

We need

```
realFriends(a,Z) :- friend(a,Z);friend(Z,a).
```

and

```
realFriends(Z,a) :- friend(Z,a);friend(a,Z).
```

to be true.

- The first can be made true with `Z=b`.
- The second can be made true with `Z=b`.

Comment: Thank you, but if I only take your realFriends Definition then I only get X=a, when I add your Definition to mine I get a weird solution. So actually my goal with realFriends was to make the friend relation symmetric, thus I dont have to create two facts for each friendship

Comment: I think David did not want to propose a different definition of your predicate `realFriends/2`, but show you why everyone that has any friend is one's own friend of friend ;-)

Comment: @tonik if your question was answered here, _as asked_, then mark it and post your new question as a *new* question, possibly including a link to this one. (do not ask new questions in comments; do not change your question with completely different contents). that's how SO is supposed to work, right? :)

Comment: @tiffi yeah my bad :)